# Is it possible to add subitems to TabHost in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

Is it possible to add subitems to TabHost in Android, when clicking on some item.
For example:

```
item1
item2
item3

After click on item1, we receive
item1
   item1_1
   item1_2
item2
item3
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `TabManager` in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, updated information